# Harry Potter fanfiction with Luna Lovegood as its main character

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

The main character is Luna Lovegood and shows her life with Xenophilius. I am **certain** that I found this on [FanFiction.net](https://www.fanfiction.net). Eventually, Harry and Luna develop a romance, and I specifically remember a moment where Luna and Harry bundle up together under a blanket. I also remember a moment where Luna goes swimming in the lake by Hogwarts and McGonagall yells at her because it is cold outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## *The Peculiar Life of Luna Lovegood*

The story can be found [here](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/13234218/1/The-Peculiar-Life-of-Luna-Lovegood-ORIGINAL) for anyone who is interested! I am so glad I was able to find this once more, because I didn't finish reading it, and now I can!

<sub>(Thanks, @Laurel)</sub>